# Unable to use Lazy load + Dynamic image manipulation Cloudinary

Tags: lazy-loading, cloudinary

I am unable to use the feature [Cloudinary Lazyload](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360022207572-Image-does-not-load-after-uploading-to-cloudinary?input_string=Unable%20to%20use%20Lazy%20load%20%2B%20Dynamic%20image%20manipulation%20cloudinary)  + [Dynamic image manipulation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/responsive_images#dynamic_image_manipulation) both at the same time.

Is there any trick to use both the function at the same time?

I am using an HTML website.

My code is

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cloudinary-core@latest/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
         var cl = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({cloud_name: "syg"}); 
         // replace 'demo' with your cloud name in the line above 
         cl.responsive();
</script>
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, imgObserver) => {
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                        const lazyImage = entry.target
                        console.log("lazy loading ", lazyImage)
                        lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src
                    }
                })
            });
            const arr = document.querySelectorAll('img.lzy_img')
            arr.forEach((v) => {
                imageObserver.observe(v);
            })
        })
</script>
```

```html
<img class="cld-responsive lzy_img"  data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/syg/image/upload/w_auto,c_scale/sample.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The responsive script will apply the relevant width value and replace `w_auto` in the URL based on the container size.
Since your code does not limit the `<img>` container, it applies the max width size of the screen.

For testing purposes, you can wrap your `<img>` element with `<div style="width:50%;"></div>` and you will see that the image URL adjusts the width transformation accordingly:

```
<div style="width:50%;">
  <img class="cld-responsive lzy_img" data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/syg/image/upload/w_auto,c_scale/v346346/sample.jpg"/>
</div>
```

In addition, you can take a look at the following broader implementation of [LQIP+Lazy Loading+Responsive](https://codepen.io/leptians/pen/MRYBOM) with Cloudinary for reference and ideas on how to implement these features within your site's pages.

Comment: Can I have some easy methods? I have more than 50 images to load both using lazy load and Dynamic image manipulation. In your method, I have to write down all the image's names in the javascript and that will be too lengthy process.

Comment: I am loading image inside a div


<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
         <img class="cld-responsive lzy_img" data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/syg/image/upload/w_auto,c_scale/v346346/sample.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
         <img class="cld-responsive lzy_img" data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/syg/image/upload/w_auto,c_scale/v346346/sample.jpg"/>
      </div>     
   </div>
</div>